# Windows Network Share Freezes When Inactive After Ten Minutes

Tags: file-sharing, smb, unresponsive

I have 4 network shares being shared out from a server. I can interact with them like normal. However, if I do not interact with shares for around ten minutes, the shares freeze up when trying to use them. *Every time.*

For example, I will be writing a document, or moving a file, etc. and will take a ten minute break. When I try to pick up where I left off, the entire share times out. If I am interacting with a file through an application (like a text editor) the program becomes unresponsive as well.

I have checked the autodisconnect feature with `net config server` and the idle session time is set to `-1`, meaning it never disconnects.

This happens on every computer, on every share, every time.

What can I do to troubleshoot this?
Has anyone ran into this issue as was able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what version of Windows Server you are using but have you tried looking into the CMD line recommendation here?: [Mapped Drive Connection Lost](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/297684/mapped-drive-connection-to-network-share-may-be-lost)

Here is a summary in case the website link changes in the future:

> To change the default time-out period for the autodisconnect feature of the Server service, open a command prompt, type the following line, and then press ENTER
>
> net config server /autodisconnect:**number**
>
> Where **number** is the number of minutes that you want the server to wait before it disconnects a mapped network drive. The maximum value for this command is 65,535.
>
> NOTE: If you set the autodisconnect value to **0** (zero), the autodisconnect feature is not turned off, and the Server service disconnects mapped network drives after only a few seconds of idle time.

You probably want to figure out how long it should stay active, as the more active connections there are the larger the load on the server will be.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have checked what the value is with `net config server` and the autodisconnect is set to `-1`. Having no timeout wouldn't be the cause would it?